# Какую java библиотеку использовать для выявления ключевых слов в тексте?

Tags: java, nlp

Всем привет, хотелось бы узнать, какие java библиотеки подходят для анализа русского текста ( а именно для выявления ключевых слов в тексте). Если это имеет значение, текст не длинный - до 500 слов.

Answer (score 0):

Из самых известных библиотек можно предложить посмотреть `Lucene` и возможности `OpenNLP`. Кстати, по этой теме уже был опрос на английском StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447045/java-library-for-keywords-extraction-from-input-text